# Install R in Jupyterhub

Tags: python, rpy2, jupyter-irkernel

I plan on use R inside Python using the rpy2 package in Jupyterhub.

I'm using conda 4.9.2

```
$ conda install -c r r-essentials
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
- conda==4.8.1
```

and trying to downgrad conda 4.8.1, But this error occured.

```
EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you a user of JupyterHub, or an administrator?

Comment: im a user. Have no authority.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of easy way to work this around (other than contacting your administrator and asking them to install these packages).